# How to develop antivirus, I want a book for reference

Tags: antivirus

I want to develop antivirus software but I do not know how to make.

I tried to search book of antivirus SW, but there's no book for reference.

If you know the good reference to develop antivirus SW, plz let me know.

Comment: First try to understand software security term, then you can easily find book and references related to this topic.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A book would be one method if you can find it, or you could take the more dangerous path and set yourself up an isolated computer and go and FIND viruses and malware and figure out what they do, how they work, and how you can remove them.

If you want to write antivirus, you're first going to need to understand how all the various kinds of viruses do their thing. What holes they exploit, what they do to the computer, etc., etc.

Oh, and new viruses and variations on viruses are being released all the time so to keep your antivirus worthwhile, it will need to either be smarter and more robust than any antivirus to date, or you will need to continually update it to combat new techniques.